# How do I onclick/addeventlistener to an EJS template?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to build a database using mongodb where it will render to an html page using ejs. Backend is node/express.

How do I link the button to an `addeventlistener`. EJS documentation is limited and I've read other posts that says ejs only renders html but no other functionality.

Eventually, I would like to use an async/await to link the js with the backend.

Here is my ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>The Beautiful Game</h1>
    <form action="/players" method="POST">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="club" name="club" />
      <button type="submit" class='submitButton'>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <h2>Players</h2>

    <ul class="players">
      <% for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {%>
      <li class="players">
        <span><%= players[i].name %></span>:
        <span><%= players[i].club %></span>
        <button class="dataDeleteNameButton" data-id="<%=players[i]._id%>">Delete</button> <!-- linking this button -->
      </li>
      <% } %>
    </ul>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my js:

```
document
  .querySelector("dataDeleteNameButton")
  .addEventListener("click", deleteEntry);

async function deleteEntry() {
  console.log("Button is working!");
}
```

Here is the server, if needed:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(cors());

const username = "hidden";
const password = "hidden";
const connectionString = `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@cluster0.7k2ww.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

MongoClient.connect(connectionString, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then((client) => {
    console.log("Connected to database");
    const db = client.db("soccer-players");
    const playerCollection = db.collection("players");

    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(express.static("public"));

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      db.collection("players")
        .find()
        .toArray()
        .then((result) => {
          res.render("index.ejs", { players: result });
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    });

    app.get("/api/players", (req, res) => {
      db.collection("players")
        .find()
        .toArray((err, arr) => {
          res.json(arr);
        });
    });

    app.post("/players", (req, res) => {
      playerCollection
        .insertOne(req.body)
        .then((result) => {
          res.redirect("/");
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
      console.log(req.body);
    });

    app.delete("/", (req, res) => {
      // playerCollection.deleteOne() <-- 
      // let findID = 
    });

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Picture of what it looks like:

[image: player database]

This is my script tag path:  `../client-side-folder/js-folder/main.js`

Directory:

```
main-folder
+--client-side-folder
+----js-folder
+------main.js
+--views-folder
+----index.ejs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `onclick="myFunction(theIdOfTheButtonHere)"`

Here is an example:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: I used `addeventlistener`. I edited my path in my original. Can you please see if that's correct?